# Ruby functions vs methods

Tags: ruby, function, lambda, methods

In the [Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177), Chapter 6 (second paragraph) they state:

> Many languages distinguish between
>   functions, which have no associated
>   object, and methods, which are invoked
>   on a receiver object. Because Ruby is
>   a purely object oriented language, all
>   methods are true methods and are
>   associated with at least one object.

And then in the middle of the 6th paragraph:

> Both procs and lambdas are functions
>   rather than methods invoked on an
>   object.

I am a bit confused about these statements. Is Ruby truly pure OO, and therefore doesn't have functions that aren't associated with objects (if that is a valid definition of pure OO), or are procs/lambdas associated with the Proc object? What is the difference between functions and methods in Ruby?

Any help in parsing and understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`lambda`s in Ruby are objects of class Proc.  `Proc` objects don't belong to any object.  They are called without binding them to an object.

Methods are objects of either class `Method` or `UnboundMethod`, depending on whether they're bound or unbound.  See the explanation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/UnboundMethod.html).  Unbound methods can't be called until they're bound to an object.

```
lambda{|x| x}.class      # => Proc
lambda{|x| x}.call(123)  # => 123

class Foo
  def bar(baz)
    baz
  end
end

puts Foo.new.method(:bar).class     # => Method
puts Foo.new.method(:bar).call(123) # => 123

puts Foo.instance_method(:bar).class     # => UnboundMethod
puts Foo.instance_method(:bar).call(123) # => throws an exception
```

You can `bind` an `UnboundMethod` to an object and then call it.  But you can't `bind` a `Proc` to an object at all.  `Proc` objects can however capture local variables in the surrounding scope, becoming closures.

Comment: Methods are not objects. The `Object#method` returns a `Method`, but othewise a method is not a `Method`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not

Answer (score 5):

Procs and lambdas are both objects unto themselves, with a `call` method that actually invokes the block associated with the proc (or lambda). However, Ruby provides some syntactic sugar to invoke them without the explicit call to `call`.

Comment: Yes, proc's and lambdas are both Proc objects, but what do they mean  by "are functions rather than methods." And what is the distinction?

Comment: He means the sentence in the middle of the 6th paragraph is inaccurate.

Comment: The difference is really that, almost universally, procs and lambdas are only used for their associated 'call' method.  No one stores additional methods or values with them.  So, like Kaptajn Kold says, we can use them as we would use first order functions in other languages, even though they are still really objects.

Comment: So in a sense Procs and lambdas are technically "methods" because everything in Ruby is an object, but in practice they behave like "functions" would in other languages—they are anonymous bits of code that aren't bound to a specific object (other than the Proc class)?

Answer (score 5):

I think the distinction is between methods and [first order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_order_functions) ie. functions that can be passed around as values.