# in ruby is there a distinction between a method and function

Tags: ruby, function, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby functions vs methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928443/ruby-functions-vs-methods)

Im just reading some ruby documentation and t seems to use the term function and method in an interchangeable way, i jut wanted to know if there is any distinction?

the docs im looking at refer to this as a function:

```
def saysomething()
  puts "Hello"
end

saysomething
```

and this a method:

```
def multiply(val1, val2 )
  result = val1 * val2
  puts result
end
```

this may be a something semantic but i wanted to check

jt

Comment: There are no functions in Ruby. Period. You should file a bug / contact the author for that documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Ruby, there are not two separate concepts of methods and functions. Some people still use both terms, but in my opinion, using "function" when talking about Ruby is incorrect. There do not exist executable pieces of code that are not defined on objects, because there is nothing in Ruby that is not an object.

As Dan pointed out, there's a way to call methods that makes them *look* like functions, but the underlying thing is still a method. You can actually see this for yourself in IRB with the `method` method.

```
> def zomg; puts "hi"; end
#=> nil
> method(:zomg)
#=> #<Method: Object#zomg>
> Object.private_instance_methods.sort
#=> [..., :zomg]
# the rest of the list omitted for brevity
```

So you can see, the method `zomg` is an instance method on Object, and is included in Object's list of private instance methods.