# Call a method before all other methods

Tags: ruby

Here is an excerpt from my module:

```rb
module Helpers
  def self.reflect(callers_binding, callers_name)
    callers_method = caller_locations.first.label
    callers_instance = Module.const_get callers_name
    callers_parameters = callers_instance
      .method(callers_method)
      .parameters.map do |_, arg_name|
        [arg_name, callers_binding.local_variable_get(arg_name)]
      end
    callers_parameters = Hash[callers_parameters]
    puts "#{callers_instance}.#{callers_method}: #{callers_parameters}"
  end
end

module MyModule
  def self.foo(arg1, arg2)
    Helpers.reflect binding, self.to_s
    puts arg1, arg2
  end

  def self.bar(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    Helpers.reflect binding, self.to_s
    puts arg1, arg2, arg3
  end
end
```

1. As seen, I would like to print a debug information using `Helpers.reflect()`. rather then writing explicitly in each function `Helpers.reflect binding, self.to_s`, is there any way to instruct ruby to execute `Helpers.reflect binding, self.to_s` before all functions in the module (except for `Helpers.reflect` itself) and avoiding writing it explicitly?
2. How can `Helpers.reflect()` method be improved, providing less (or zero) argument to it?

Comment: Can you provide one or more examples, showing desired return values?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module) ?

Comment: They're methods (not functions) in Ruby. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8393331/3784008), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/928443/3784008), [ref](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls).

Comment: @Karnaj: thank you for the reference, although i haven't tried it, comments say it is not compatiable with ruby 2.7, and i couldn't understand how do i pass a variable to `before()` as i need to pass `binding` and `self.to_s`. i've updated my post

Comment: @CarySwoveland: i've updated my question. would you kindly help? :)